# Why an elastic rod cools when stretched?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, material-science

When we extend (figure from [Concepts in Thermal Physics](https://academic.oup.com/book/26407)) an elastic rod isothermally (and reversibly) the amount of heat transferred to the system equals:

$$ΔQ = ΤΔS = A \cdot E_T \cdot T \cdot a_f \cdot ΔL$$

Since entropy change is positive, heat is absorbed from the system. In order for the system to absorb heat, momentarily its temperature must be decreased (so that heats flow from environment to the system).

What is the microscopic origin of that momentarily temperature drop?

**Comments**

In order for temperature to decrease momentarily, kinetic energy must go down momentarily.

When we extend the rod we increase the interatomic spacing (analogous to extending a one dimensional string), which means that potential energy is increased. Obviously, there is no reduction in the kinetic energy from that extension.

[image]

Comment: Simple toy model: think of a string on a table there is a single way of having the string fully stretched but there are many ways it could be not stretched.

Comment: @Mauricio How this explain the momentarily temperature drop?

Comment: Entropy decreases in the string example.

Comment: @Mauricio I understand the entropy decrease. The question was about the microscopic origin of the momentarily temperature decrease.

Comment: Isn't temperature a macroscopical observable? Do you mean that you want to know how kinetic/potential energy is modified?

Comment: @Mauricio If heat is absorbed then there must be a temperature difference between the system and the surroundings (momentarily). I want to understand micrsocopically what happens and the rod cools when extends. We know that temperature is related to the average kinetic energy which means that molecules of the rod must somehow lower their kinetic energy. This is the modification of KE that I am seeking of.

Answer (score 3):

If the stretching is reversible then the entropy associated with the rod does not change.

As the rod is stretched the increase in the entropy due to the larger separation of the atoms is compensated for by an equal decrease in the entropy due the thermal motion of the atoms decreasing and a lower thermal kinetic energy of the atoms corresponds to a lower temperature.
Once the rod is stretched to go back to its initial temperature the rod must absorb heat from its surroundings.

Note that for rubber stretching aligns the rubber molecules and this results in a reduction in entropy so the thermal motion of the rubber molecules must increase so that there is no overall change in the entropy.
Once the rod is stretched to go back to its initial temperature the rod must give out heat to its surroundings.

Comment: Why the change in entropy of rod is zero for a reversible extension? Reversible process means that the entropy of the system + surroundings doesn't change (system can increase or decrease its entropy).